# How to pass the TS type checking for component props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props

```
export const Component: React.FC<SpaProps> = function({
    a,
    b,
    c,
    d
})
```

a, b, c belong to SpaProps. However, d doesn't. How I can add a prop type, which  supports a,b,c,d together? BTW I know what the type for d

```
export interface IT {
    d: AxiosInstance;
}
```

Comment: Change the signature to `React.FC<SpaProps & d>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend the type with Typescript like this:

```js
export const Component: React.FC<SpaProps & IT> = function({
    a,
    b,
    c,
    d
})
```

Even if you didn't know the type, you could write it like this:

```js
export const Component: React.FC<SpaProps & {d: AxiosInterface}> = function({
    a,
    b,
    c,
    d
})
```

Comment: one further question here: Does & mean extend? thanks

Comment: `&` is the union of two types. It is not the same as extending a class for example.

Comment: Isn't "|" the union type?

Comment: Yes, I think they call `&` an [Intersection Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types) in the Typescript docs. But imho it is a bit misleading, because it combines two types and not only the intersection of both types. It is very similar to the union type.